# QGIS SAGA Overland flow distance to channel network not working

Tags: qgis-3, saga

I am trying to run the QGIS SAGA tool "Overland flow distance to channel network" with a DEM and the channel network raster developed from this same DEM using the SAGA tool "Channel network." However, I am getting an error: 
"Error: Channel Network"
I'm using QGIS 3.4.2-Madeira.
What could the problem be? Has this tool worked for anyone?

Comment: The tool is working properly in my environment and I cannot reproduce the error. Could you edit your question to include full Error messages and Log output?